# MySQL not starting because of galera config

Tags: mysql, galera

I have mysql installed on Ubuntu machine and it is working fine. But as soon as I add the galera conf the mysql doesn't start. 
Below is the command I am using.

```
root@Abhishek-Dev-D1:/usr/local# /etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
Starting MySQL
.... * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
```

**Galera.conf**

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.31.254.196,172.31.254.197,172.31.254.198"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="172.31.254.196"
wsrep_node_name="node1"
```

When I remove galera.conf from `/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.conf` and then start mysql is starting properly.

When I installed it for the first time it was working fine but then during testing I issued a reboot command on one of the node. After that mysql doesn't booted up with galera.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?  What version of MariaDB/PXC/MySQL?  Is the _first_ node giving you trouble?

Comment: I suppose `mysql` logs could be useful here.